# Selenium GeckoDriver with Protractor: "Failed: Timed out"

Tags: selenium, protractor, timeout, geckodriver

My automation test suite uses Selenium WebDriver with Protractor and Jasmine to run against a variety of browsers.  When using GeckoDriver to run the tests on Firefox, I am intermittently getting an error message that just says "Failed: Timed out":

```
.    ✓ WHEN I visit the favorites page
.    ✓ THEN it should say I havent added anything
F    ✗ WHEN I open the inspirations page
      - Failed: Timed out
      Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T19:05:32.194Z'
      System info: host: 'admins-MacBook-Pro-3.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:10a7:9b8d:6ff5:f46%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.6', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
      Driver info: driver.version: unknown
F    ✗ AND I click on an inspiration preview pane to open an inspiration
```

I have tried padding it with hard-coded sleep on either side, and I've searched for other errors, but everything else I can find in regards to Protractor timeouts is for other errors that have some kind of a description about what is actually timing out.

Has anyone seen JUST the message "Failed: Timed out" here who can help determine what might be timing out?

As requested, here is the gulp task that kicks off my protractor:

```
gulp.task('test-frontend-firefox', 'Run feature tests locally', function() {
  gulp.src(['test/feature/**/*.spec.js'])
    .pipe(protractor({
      configFile: __dirname + '/../test/protractor_local_ff.conf.js',
      args: ['--baseUrl', 'http://localhost:9099'],
    }));
});
```

And here is protractor_local_ff.conf.js as referenced by the gulp task:

```
var private_config = require('./private.conf.js');
var golden_config = require('./golden.conf.js');
exports.config = {
  params: {
    private: private_config,
    golden: golden_config,
    localhost: true
  },
  onPrepare: function(){
    var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter').SpecReporter;
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({displayStacktrace: 'all'}));
  },
  framework: 'jasmine2',
  // seleniumAddress: 'http://hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'firefox'
  }
};
```

As you can see, it's set up to be able to run against the hosted app in either browserstack or on my localhost, but the error gets thrown intermittently in either environment.

Comment: Can you show the code block you are using to configure the driver and initialize the Web Browser?

Comment: @DebanjanB - thanks.  I edited the question to include that info.

Comment: Do you have `jasmineNodeOpts.defaultTimeoutInterval ` set somewhere ?

Comment: The error has stopped throwing now that I've broken the code into smaller "it"  blocks which define each test in Jasmine.  It very possibly seems to be an error thrown by Jasmine, my test runner.

Comment: @Barney I have jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 100000; in my Jasmine beforeAll block but I think it throws a different and more descriptive error if that times out.... I'm no longer getting the plain "Failed: Timed out" error but I am still really curious as to what caused it.

Comment: I am in fact still getting the "Failed: Timed out" error with no stack trace.  I'm not sure whether my assumption that it's coming from Jasmine is correct or not, but it certainly isn't taking 100000ms before it is thrown